# Powershell - Copy files only from the current day and if they don't exist in the target directory

Tags: powershell, file, date, directory, copy

I'm trying to develop a script that copy .txt files from two source folders to one destination folder.

I would like as well to add 2 additional conditions:

1. If a file already exists in the target directory, skip it
2. The copied files must not be older than the current day

This is what I made, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
$SourceDirItemsMITEMAvail = "\\wipfs02\Data\webshop\test\ecomcloud_import\carhartt\product\*"
$SourceDirCaproBPRIC = "\\wipfs02\Data\webshop\test\hybris_import\carhartt\product\*"
$TargetDirB2B = "\\wipfs02\Data\webshop\test\ecomcloud_import\carhartt\b2b\product\"

$ExcludeSubDir = "archive", "IDISC Test", "save", "archive_B2B", "archive_tmp", "Errors"

# Copy only the specific files
$SpecificTypesEcomCloudImport = "avail*", "items*", "MITEM*"
$SpecificTypesHybrisImport = "BPRIC*", "CAPRO*"

# Get the current date
$CurrentDateFiles = (Get-Date).Date

# Copy items from source directories and transfer them to the B2B Folder
For ($i=0; $i -lt $SourceDirItemsMITEMAvail.Count -and $SourceDirCaproBPRIC.Count; $i++) {

    #  If the copied files don't already exist into the target directory, then copy them
    if (-not(Test-Path -Path $SourceDirItemsMITEMAvail, $SourceDirCaproBPRIC)) {

    try {
        # The copied files must not be older that the current day
        $CopyFilesEcomCloudImportDir = Copy-Item $SourceDirItemsMITEMAvail -Exclude $ExcludeSubDir -Destination $TargetDirB2B -PassThru -Verbose -Include $SpecificTypesEcomCloudImport | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -eq $CurrentDateFiles}
        Write-Host ""$CopyFilesEcomCloudImportDir.Count" file(s) have been copied from $SourceDirItemsMITEMAvail to $TargetDirB2B."

        # The copied files must not be older that the current day
        $CopyFilesHybrisImportDir = Copy-Item $SourceDirCaproBPRIC -Exclude $ExcludeSubDir -Destination $TargetDirB2B -PassThru -Verbose -Include $SpecificTypesHybrisImport | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -eq $CurrentDateFiles}
        Write-Host ""$CopyFilesHybrisImportDir.Count" file(s) have been copied from $SourceDirCaproBPRIC to $TargetDirB2B."
    }
    catch {
        "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
    }else {
        Write-Host "Cannot copy $CopyFilesEcomCloudImportDir because a file with that name already exists in the destination folder."
        Write-Host "Cannot copy $CopyFilesHybrisImportDir because a file with that name already exists in the destination folder."
    }
}
```

Either it copies all the files from the sources directories, or it goes immediately to the else condition.

If I remove the if (Test-Path) condition, it copies all the files from the sources, even those who are older than the current day.

If I let the if (Test-Path) condition, it goes immediately to the else statement.

Could you help me to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Why not user [Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) instead? It sports a lot of options and features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just PowerShell, you could do this:

```
$SourceDirItemsMITEMAvail = "\\wipfs02\Data\webshop\test\ecomcloud_import\carhartt\product"
$SourceDirCaproBPRIC      = "\\wipfs02\Data\webshop\test\hybris_import\carhartt\product"
$TargetDirB2B             = "\\wipfs02\Data\webshop\test\ecomcloud_import\carhartt\b2b\product"
$ExcludeSubDir            = "archive", "IDISC Test", "save", "archive_B2B", "archive_tmp", "Errors"

# create a regex of the folders to exclude
# each folder will be Regex Escaped and joined together with the OR symbol '|'
$notThese = ($ExcludeSubDir | ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

# Copy only the specific files
##############################
# if all files are .txt files, change the patterns below to include that:
# like "avail*.txt", "items*.txt", "MITEM*.txt","BPRIC*.txt", "CAPRO*.txt"
##############################
$FileNamePattern = "avail*", "items*", "MITEM*","BPRIC*", "CAPRO*"

# Get the current date
$today = (Get-Date).Date

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDirItemsMITEMAvail, $SourceDirCaproBPRIC -Include $FileNamePattern -File -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -notmatch $notThese -and $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq $today } |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $TargetDirB2B -ChildPath $_.Name
        if (Test-Path -Path $targetFile -PathType Leaf) {
            Write-Host "File '$targetFile' already exists. Skipping"
        }
        else {
            $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $TargetDirB2B -Force
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I however got an error while launching the script with -Filter parameter. I modified it with -Include and add a \* for the sources directories, Now I see that only the avail* txt are transferred to the target directory.

Comment: @VictorLeclerc Sorry, my bad... `-Filter` should have been `-Include`. I have also added an extra inline comment to adjust the patterns if all files to be copied are .txt files.

Comment: No problem, I see now that only the current avail*.txt files are copied to my destination folder, even if I remove $FileNamePattern from the script. Is there a way to adjust this?

Comment: @VictorLeclerc Can you add a `Write-Host $notThese` after the line where variable `$notThese` is defined? It should show a string `archive|IDISC\ Test|save|archive_B2B|archive_tmp|Errors`. I cannot see any of the real filenames of course, but perhaps you should do the patterns like `"*avail*.txt", "*items*.txt", "*MITEM*.txt","*BPRIC*.txt", "*CAPRO*.txt"` because they may not all start with any of these keywords?

Comment: Yes exactly I got this:  archive|IDISC\ Test|save|archive_B2B|archive_tmp|Errors

Comment: I also added a * * to the patterns, but the result I got is the same. I only see avail files be transferred to my target folder.

Comment: @VictorLeclerc Can you check if expected-to-be-copied files indeed are last modified today?  (that is the second requirement in the Where-Object clause)

Comment: Indeed, you're right! I checked the sources folder, and except the avail files, there was no other types of files from the current day. I tested with one MITEM and it was transferred to the target directory. Thanks

Comment: @VictorLeclerc Ah, good to hear that! Was busy testing, but couldn't find any other reason.